History of the notion of integral ring extension?
[I asked that question in "history of science and mathematics" but didn't get any answer so I take my chance here. I hope this is not out of context]
Can anyone give me references about the history of the notion of integral ring extensions in number theory ?
The theory is nicely displayed when presented in books nowadays, but I really wonder how the number theorists of the 19th century-beginings of the 20th century came up with the fact that the right definition of an "integer" in a number field has to do with the notion of integral dependence on the base ring.

link to the HSM question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/17905/1697

The early landmark papers are Dedekind's supplements on algebraic number theory where integral elements were first defined properly, van der Waerden's algebra, and Emmy Noether's characterization of Dedekind rings. The first two sources are available in English. Afterwards, the theory was gradually "bourbakified"; this developed in parallel to algebra becoming more and more abstract.
